# Bootstrap positionement inside a block

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a responsive bootstrap design based on this picture
[image]

What I have done :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row NameJob">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, what are you suggestions for the inside of right box?
I'm looking for easiest solution and also the most responsive one.

Comment: What have your tried, hwo far did you get towards this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simples way could be this a left column of 4 and a righ column of 8 :

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row NameJob">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">data 1</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-2 pull">data 2 </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10"></div>
                    ......... 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```